# Position an image not inside a <DIV> tag inside that div

Tags: html, positioning

Can I position an image inside a div when it is not enclosed within the  tag? What I'm asking is, if I had an image not in a div, could I use something like relative positioning to position it inside the div on the screen? (It would still be outside the div in the HTML).

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this?  Yes it's possible.

Comment: I have an image that is opaque, but a div that is transparent.  I want the image to be on top of the div, and still be opaque.  I would have included that, I just thought it irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this work with relative or absolute positioning:
http://jsfiddle.net/5H9QT/

```
#container{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#image{
    position:relative;
    top:-200px;
}
```

Comment: Could I have the position update based on the position of the div?

Answer (score 0):

Yes: http://jsfiddle.net/nfrdF/

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` and set the `padding: ?px` and `margin: ?px` accordingly under the style.

Comment: Wouldn't absolute positioning position it in the absolute position of the screen, not the relative position of the div?

Comment: no, it would position it in a absolute position to the parent div with absolute/relative position.